# O365 bulk license

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory, office365, licensing

I am using this powershell script below to license bulk users in office365 by .csv file. The script will only work if the .csv file header is:

UserPrincipalName
example@jackson.k12.ms.us

But our .csv is formatted: "Alias","UPN"

```
                     "myrobinson","myrobinson@jackson.k12.ms.us"
```

I want to know how to recode this script so it works with our .csv file?

```
$path= Import-Csv -Path "\\11.10.38.142\Users\myrobinson\NewUsers.csv"
foreach ($item in $path){

$MSOLUserName= $item.UserPrincipalName

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "support@Jpsd" -AsPlainText –Force

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("admin@jpsd.onmicrosoft.com",$password)

$cred = Get-Credential -cred $credential

Import-Module MSOnline

Connect-Msolservice -cred $cred

$AccountSkuId = "jpsd:STANDARDWOFFPACK_FACULTY" 

$UsageLocation = "US" 

$LicenseOptions = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId $AccountSkuId 

Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $MSOLUserName -UsageLocation $UsageLocation

Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $MSOLUserName -AddLicenses 

$AccountSkuId  -LicenseOptions $LicenseOptions

}
```

Comment: Why not just change the header in the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace $item.UserPrincipalName with $item.UPN.

Comment: Thats the first thing I tried, but it didn't work that's why i came here for help.. I think that UserPrincipalName is a unique name that O365 uses.

Comment: Mykal I don't see where O365 gets a "UserPrincipalName" or alternative value. You're passing a $MSOLUserName variable as an argument (twice) so your problem does not have to do with member or variable names. Paste the error message you're getting.

Comment: Set-MsolUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'UPN'.
At line:11 char:18
+ Set-MsolUser -UPN <<<<  $MSOLUserName -UsageLocation $UsageLocation
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MsolUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUser
Set-MsolUserLicense : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'UPN'.
At line:12 char:25

Comment: + Set-MsolUserLicense -UPN <<<<  $MSOLUserName -AddLicenses $AccountSkuId  -LicenseOptions $LicenseOptions
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MsolUserLicense], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUserLicense

Set-MsolUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'UPN'.
At line:11 char:18
+ Set-MsolUser -UPN <<<<  $MSOLUserName -UsageLocation $UsageLocation
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MsolUser], ParameterBindingException

Comment: Mykal command arguments cannot be changed or created on the run. -UPN is not a supported argument for Set-MsolUser command. Import your CSV and use it like this: Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $item.UPN